# changing pattern of a text file

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression, awk

A text file has contents something like

```
chair
table
pen
desk
```

Now i want it to be changed and stored in a variable say `var` as below

**('chair','chair'),('table','table'),('pen','pen'),('desk','desk')**

is it possible?

**EDIT**
Jofel's anser gave following error

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g;s/\w*/(''&'',''&'')/g' -i csclm.txt
sed: The label :a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g;s/\w*/(&,&)/g is greater than eight characters.
```

I am using :

```
$ uname -a
HP-UX rcihp145 B.11.23 U 9000/800 3683851961 unlimited-user license
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `sed`:

Content of **script.sed**:

```
## Change line.
s/.*/('&','&')/

## Append it to hold space.
H

## In end of file substitute newlines with commas and print.
$ {
    g   
    s/^\n//
    s/\n/,/g
    p   
}
```

Command:

```
sed -nf script.sed infile
```

Output:

```
('chair','chair'),('table','table'),('pen','pen'),('desk','desk')
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a subprocess, it can be done in pure bash shell:

```
var=$(while read line; do echo -n ",('$line','$line')"; done < file)
var=${var:1}
```

**Update**:

If you want this as a one-liner, you could:

```
var=$({ read line && echo -n "('$line','$line')" && while read line; do echo -n ",('$line','$line')"; done } < file)
```

Note the `&&` to perform `echo` and `while`only it the file is non-empty.

Comment: ++++1 this looks nice and short

Comment: Hi @jfgagne but the first comma will come and the output will be start something like **,(**.........

Comment: Yes, the 1st comma will will come from the 1st command.  This is why you need to add `var=${var:1}` as a 2nd command to stripe the 1st character.  I think it is easier to proceed that way than to manage the 1st line in a different way, but I will update the post.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure shell method: read every line, and append the properly massaged data to `var`. Strip off the extra comma.

```
var=
while IFS= read -r line; do
  var="$var,('$line','$line')"
done <input_file
var=${var#,}
```

Here's a simple method using external utilities: massage each line with `sed`, then turn the newlines into commas. Strip off the extra comma.

```
var=$(<input_file sed "s/.*/('\1','\1')/" | tr "\n" ',')
var=${var%,}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution not with `awk`, but with `sed`:

To do the replacement in FILENAME, run

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g;s/\w*/(''&'',''&'')/g' -i FILENAME
```

For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n).

Comment: thanks for the sugestion, but it did not run.it gave

Comment: `$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g;s/\w*/(''&'',''&'')/g' -i csclm.txt
sed: The label :a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g;s/\w*/(&,&)/g is greater than eight characters.`

Comment: +1 i like your answer anyway i am going to look into it.Its a step in the right direction

Comment: For me it runs without any problems. I tried it with GNU sed 4.2.1 and zsh/bash as shell.

Comment: You seems to use non-GNU sed. According to [this discussion](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/115767-join-lines-line-break-files.html), it should work for you if you use real newlines instead of `;` between the sed commands.

Answer (score 1):

A very complicated way to do it, working only in the bash shell (because of process substitution), but using only simple commands:

```
var=$(sed -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/\$/'/" file |
  paste -d "," - <(sed -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/\$/'/" file) |
  sed -e "s/^/(/" -e "s/\$/)/" |
  paste -s -d ",")
```